# python dealing with SSH [many clients ]

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

i mange 3 server [ Linux ] and i have to turn on scripts on these servers every 6 hours

so it's take a lite bit time to login in each one .. so i made this code

```
import paramiko
import os
ZI1={"ip":"192.168.1.2","pass":"server-1"}
ZI2={"ip":"192.168.1.3","pass":"Server-2"}
ZI3={"ip":"192.168.1.4","pass":"server-3"}
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
SPAM=1
while SPAM==3:
    ssh.connect(ZI1["ip"],username='root', password=ZI1["pass"])
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('perl Register.pl')
    print stdout.readlines()
    SPAM+=1
    ssh.connect(ZI2["ip"],username='root', password=ZI2["pass"])
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('perl Register.pl')
    print stdout.readlines()
    SPAM+=1
    ssh.connect(ZI2["ip"],username='root', password=ZI2["pass"])
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('perl Register.pl')
    print stdout.readlines()
    ssh.close()
    SPAM+=1
```

well it's not working as well ;( i wana to enter each one and run the script and go to 
another server without closing the connection or terminating the script so please help me.

### after edit

now i edit it and i got new issues

i add this to my code :

```
import paramiko
import os
ZI1={"ip":"192.168.1.2","pass":"server-1"}
ZI2={"ip":"192.168.1.3","pass":"Server-2"}
ZI3={"ip":"192.168.1.4","pass":"server-3"}
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

for F1 in ZI1:
    ssh.connect(ZI1["ip"],username='root', password=ZI1["pass"])
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('uname -a')
    print stdout.readlines()
    ssh.close()
for F2 in ZI2:
    ssh.connect(ZI2["ip"],username='root', password=ZI2["pass"])
    ssh.exec_command('ls -la')
    print stdout.readlines()
    ssh.close()
for F3 in ZI3:
    ssh.connect(ZI2["ip"],username='root', password=ZI2["pass"])
    ssh.exec_command('pwd')
    print stdout.readlines()
    ssh.close()
```

and i give each one different command to see does it work  and i got very stranger output

`['Linux xxxx 2.6.18-028stab070.14 #1 SMP Thu Nov 18 16:04:02 MSK 2010 x
86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux\n']
['Linux xxxx 2.6.18-028stab070.14 #1 SMP Thu Nov 18 16:04:02 MSK 2010 x
86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux\n']
[]
[]
[]
[]`

i said first server do the command `uname -a` and second one do the command `ls -la` but it's give them together the same command third server doesn't execute anything

Comment: what "does not work as well"? The connection is closed?

Comment: Your code has a logic problem. The `while` block will never execute. Not that this is your main problem, but one of them.

Comment: so what i have to do if the `while` block will never execute !?  and hey my friend zengr i mean totally script not working as well !

Comment: Perhaps you should run through the [Python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/index.html) one more time before doing something like this. Your code would be greatly improved with some better structuring, like placing ZI1..3 in a list and iterating over that list using `for`. You don't even need the `SPAM` variable at all.

Comment: Why don't you just run the script from cron on the remote hosts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for F1 in ZI1:
```

What the fried monkey are you trying to do here? For is repeating something, but you don't want to repeat anything.

Do you see the difference between these two lines of code:

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('uname -a')

ssh.exec_command('ls -la')
```

Your second and third servers are both still using the stdout from the first server. You need to have the stdin, stdout, stderr again.

Answer (score 2):

You probably should be using Fabric to do this. It would be a lot simpler for you.

Comment: ["Fabric is a Python (2.5 or higher) library and command-line tool for streamlining the use of SSH for application deployment or systems administration tasks."](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/index.html)

Comment: Google broke for you?  [Fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.0.1/index.html).  Or 'pip install fabric'.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your problem is that you're calling `stdout.readlines()`, which is going to continue to read the output from the SSH command until there is no more input to read... so your program doesn't advance until then. As a simple solution, you can execute each command in its own thread, or you can `fork` and execute it in its own process space.

Comment: so the problem is my script does't connecting as i guess ... can some one give me little hints <3

Comment: After reading Winston's answer, I have to agree with him about frying monkeys. A bit of a closer examination of your code reveals that the entire thing is one massive

Comment: Winston Ewert < so how to get new one !?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you are approaching this problem from the wrong end...

Instead of making a connection from remote host, why don't you better set up [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) scripts on the remote machines.